# UITableViewController: adding and removing iAds

Tags: ios, uitableview, iad

**Scenario** = I have a UITableViewController that will have an iAd added (via storyboards) to the top of the tableView but below the navigation bar (not in a table view cell or row). There is a BOOL value ("adsDisabled") and if the BOOL is YES, I want the ads to go away. Here is a beautiful illustration of what I am getting at...

[image]

**What I've tried** = It just makes sense that if something is 50px in height and you reduce it's height by 50 px, it should not exist (or be shown) any longer. But of course it does... This code...

```
if ([[[PFUser currentUser] objectForKey:@"adsDisabled"]isEqualToNumber:[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES]]) {

    self.adBanner.layer.frame = CGRectMake(self.adBanner.layer.frame.origin.x, self.adBanner.layer.frame.origin.y, self.adBanner.layer.frame.size.width, self.adBanner.layer.frame.size.height - 50);

    self.tableView.layer.frame = CGRectMake(self.tableView.layer.frame.origin.x, self.tableView.layer.frame.origin.y - 50, self.tableView.layer.frame.size.width, self.tableView.layer.frame.size.height);

    [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:self.navigationController.navigationBar attribute:NSLayoutAttributeBottom
                                 relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:self.tableView
                                 attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop multiplier:1.0 constant:0.0];

}

else {

    self.adBanner.layer.frame = CGRectMake(self.adBanner.layer.frame.origin.x, self.adBanner.layer.frame.origin.y, self.adBanner.layer.frame.size.width, self.adBanner.layer.frame.size.height);
}
```

Doesn't do anything.

**Work around** = I could just do...

```
self.adBanner.hidden = YES;
```

But that leaves an undesirable space between the nav bar and the first table view cell...

[image]

**Question** = How do I get the iAd to completely disappear and not leave an undesirable space in-between the nav bar and the first table view cell?

Comment: You may have an easier time using a constraint based layout. Is there any reason you can not adjust the frame of the table view as well? (-50 on the y-point of the table view)

Comment: Yes I did try that. I updated my question with the methods I have tried. Constraint based? I am finding it difficult to do in storyboards without the control+drag feature that tableviewcontrollers seem to take away. Do you know how to add a height constraint on a single view programmatically?

Comment: is there a specific reason you are adjusting the layer's frame? usually you can adjust the frame of the view itself. ex: `self.tableView.frame = CGRectMake(self.tableView.frame.origin.x, self.tableView.frame.origin.y - 50, self.tableView.frame.size.width, self.tableView.frame.size.height);`

Comment: Yeah it's just weird the way UITableViewController's seem to treat it's subviews and constraints (i guess). I worked around it. I'll post my work around up top.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried setting the ad as the tableview's header view? Then when you need to hide it set the header view to nil.

Answer (score 0):

Ok so this is what I did to make this work. I used 2 views and a AdBanner. The first view I laid down as like "the foundation" of the view 320px x 50px. THEN I placed the second view 'on top' of that view with the same dimensions as the first (320px x 50px) and set the second view's constraints |-| (top, bottom, left, right) to 0px. THEN (still with the second view) I created a **height constraint** on it set to 50px by default and created an IBOutlet for it (**important**). Next thing I would do is place the AdBanner on top of the second view with the |-| (top, bottom, left, right) to 0px of the second view. And then in code I wrote...

```
if ([[[PFUser currentUser] objectForKey:@"isPremium"]isEqualToNumber:[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES]]) {

    self.heightConstraint.constant = 0;

    self.adBanner.hidden = YES;

    self.heightView.layer.frame = CGRectMake(self.heightView.layer.frame.origin.x, self.heightView.layer.frame.origin.y, self.heightView.layer.frame.size.width, self.heightView.layer.frame.size.height - 50);

    self.backgroundView.layer.frame = CGRectMake(self.backgroundView.layer.frame.origin.x, self.backgroundView.layer.frame.origin.y, self.backgroundView.layer.frame.size.width, self.backgroundView.layer.frame.size.height - 50);
}

else {

    NSLog(@"ads visible");
}
```

Works great.